# Isolated periodic trajectories of Hamiltonian systems

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, examples, hamiltonian-mechanics

Is there any example of an autonomous Hamiltonian system with a periodic trajectory isolated in the whole phase space? The Poincar\'e map of such a trajectory within its energy level should be very degenerate, because all the energy levels with close energy values do not contain periodic trajectories: a really weird picture!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we take $H=I + \frac13(p^3 -q^3) + I^2(p-q)$ with $\omega =dI\wedge d\theta + dp\wedge dq$,

then

$\dot q = p^2 + I^2$

$\dot p = q^2 + I^2$

$\dot I = 0$

$\dot\theta = 1 + 2I(p-q)$

and the only periodic orbit is for $q=p=I=0$.

Comment: A very nice example! What is interesting is that this system is also integrable (the second integral is $I$) and reversible with respect to the phase space involution $G:(q,p,I,\theta)\mapsto(-p,-q,I,-\theta)$, and the cycle $\{q=p=I=0\}$ is invariant under $G$.

Comment: Glad you liked it! As you point out it is integrable, it shows too a difference between compact and non-compact energy levels of integrable systems (for compact levels Liouville-Arnold implies the periodic orbits come in families).

Comment: No, compactness does not matter here. Assume each of the variables $I$, $p$, $q$ to range in $[0;2\pi]$ (like $\theta$) and take $H=\sin I+\frac{1}{3}(\sin^3p-\sin^3q)+\sin^2I(\sin p-\sin q)$ with the same $\omega$, then again $I$ is another integral and $q=p=I=0$ is a periodic orbit which is no longer the only periodic orbit whatsoever, but the only periodic orbit in its neighborhood, although now the whole phase space is compact (the $4$-torus). The reason is that $dH=dI$ along the orbit. By the way, the new system is still reversible with respect to the same involution $G$.

Comment: Ah, I see thanks. It is just that the integrals are dependent along the orbit.

Answer (score 1):

Another example and many generalizations are presented in the paper

Mikhail B. Sevryuk, Integrable Hamiltonian systems with a periodic orbit or invariant torus unique in the whole phase space, arXiv:1808.03596

available at http://arxiv.org/abs/1808.03596.

Comment: See also a full-text view-only version of this paper just published "online first" in Arnold Mathematical Journal: https://link.springer.com/epdf/10.1007/s40598-018-0093-2?author_access_token=xtGomloqjdVHAh6EmYHjzPe4RwlQNchNByi7wbcMAY75cRyxmZjU-WVV2VIpU-Hy9pti-O_Fsee_j9E_EGIerWPk-DQXSo07zLtJWetNqOaty2udFQUaTfX7FTXvgjmhD3bdMtuH3ccEkGAa3X2ilA%3D%3D

Comment: Here is the complete reference: Arnold Mathematical Journal, 2018, V. 4, No. 3-4, pp. 415-422.